# debezium Mysql connector update warns on enum columns

Tags: debezium-connect

I'm getting this warning when updating debezium mysql connector from 1.7.0.Final to 2.5.0.Final

```
WARN [***|task-0] Unexpected value for JDBC type 1 and column engine_type ENUM(1) CHARSET utf8 DEFAULT VALUE NULL: class=java.lang.Integer (io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters) [***:3306]
```

Enum values are migrating as NULL values. Any suggestion how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Debezium 2.5 supports and is tested only with MySQL 8.0 which uses utf8mb4 as it's default character set.
https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-defaults-in-mysql-8-0/

As mentioned below Debezium 2.5+ support for MySQL 5.7 is only best effort:
https://debezium.io/releases/2.5/release-notes#breaking_changes_6

Likely the MySQL table your Debezium connector is trying to process has a utf8 character set. To fix the error you would need to perform a schema change to alter the character set of all your tables to utf8mb4 with desired collation.

The schema statement would be something as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

After performing the above schema change for all tables you should be able to upgrade Debezium from any pre 2.5 version to 2.5+

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. But why is this happening only with enum types? Is there any way to enable more logging to understannd which is the row that is failing?